# Linux sendfile source

Tags: linux, sendfile

Where I can get sendfile function sources?
I can't find it in kernel sources...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [Linux Cross Reference](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.36/fs/read_write.c#L809)

Answer (score 8):

Since [linux-2.6.23](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_2_6_23#head-c8fd2455c44d9559429c0f72dbc85cd54a62470d) `sendfile()` is implemented using the more generic `splice()` framework. You will find the `splice()` implementation in [fs/splice.c](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob_plain;f=fs/splice.c;hb=HEAD) under your kernel source tree.

The `sendfile()` implementation itself is in [fs/read_write.c](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob_plain;f=fs/read_write.c;hb=HEAD).